# How to embed image on top of message in telegram api

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

[image]

I found that one channel was able to embed its image inside telegram.

How can I achieve this?

Whenever I send photo. it looks like below.
[image]

How can I make the photo visible without OPNE WITH?